# Getting Exception when calling notifyCharacteristicChanged() on GattServer

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

calling `notifyCharacteristicChanged()` will throw this Exception:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1698) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1645) at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.sendNotification(IBluetoothGatt.java:1318) at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGattServer.java:539)`

here is a my code: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://gist.github.com/aryazady/11e9e939c1f12fd338be99ed7eb5bcef&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNGRzVWzu1yXVZl9efZO-4wlINdYig

Comment: Please add your source code

Comment: @M.Kotzjan Thanks for your response!
added my code

Comment: What version of Android are you testing with?

Comment: @JacquesBauer it was Android 7

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm seeing the same issue, also Android 7. Not sure how to reproduce it but it happens sometimes in production.

Comment: @jur Can't remember how I handled it, However I can remember that it was a low-level problem from the SDK itself.